# How to show that the limaçon has only two vertices.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, self-learning

**Question:** Show that the limaçon has only two vertices.

---

I researched what is *limaçon*. And I reached the following result;

[image]

---

**Note that** I only know that The limaçon is the parametrized curve
$$\gamma(t) = ((1 + 2\cos t)\cos t, (1 + 2\cos t)\sin t)$$ for $t \in \Bbb R$.

After this, I calculated $$\dot{\gamma(t)}= (-\sin t -4\cos t \sin t, \cos t +2\cos(2t)).$$

Now I need to find the points at which $\dot{\gamma (t)}=0$ .

How can I find these points? And after I find, what do I need to do in order to conclude that it has only two vertices.

I will be happy if someone show this.

Comment: What's a vertex in this setting?

Comment: According to do Carmo's "Differentiable geometry of curves and surfaces", a vertex is a point where the curvature is $0$. Why don't you compute the curvature?

Comment: I only know that The limaçon is the parametrized curve
$\gamma(t) = ((1 + 2cost)cost, (1 + 2cost)sint)$ for $t \in \Bbb R$ @Taladris

Comment: You didn't contest my definition of vertex, so I guess it is the right one. My question is still valid: why don't you compute the curvature?

Comment: Okay! How? Firstly, I calculated $$\dot{\gamma(t)}=(-sint-4costsint, cost+2cos(2t))$$ right? And then? Dear @taladris

Comment: For $t=\pi /2$? @EricStucky

Comment: @Taladris: No, a vertex is a *critical point* of curvature. Note, moreover, that on the limaçon curvature is everywhere positive.

Comment: oh yes! I misread my reference. Sorry. Should I edit my first comment for clarity?

Comment: At this point I think an answer/hint would probably be better for all involved :)

Comment: Hmm,well, at which points, this is zero? How can I find? And then, after I find these points, what do I need to do to complete the answer? Dear @EricStucky can you continue? Please:)

Comment: I am not qualified to help you. My response was an incorrect interpretation of someone else's incorrect definition. And others who are looking at this question do know what they are talking about, so I am leaving it to them.

Comment: Okay thank you Dear @Ericstucky

Comment: Dear @Taladris I show all my efforts. please give me a help. Thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the definition Ted mentioned in the comments, the vertices of a parameterised curve are the points of a curve at which the derivative of the curvature is zero (ie a critical point of curvature), and so your first action should be to calculate the curvature of $\gamma(t)$. You can do this by one of several ways, either from the definition of curvature, by reparametising the curve in terms of arc length, or by using any of the various other formulae for curvature in terms of a parametisation. I would personally use $$\kappa(t)=\frac{\|\gamma'(t)\times\gamma''(t)\|}{\|\gamma'(t)\|^3}.$$

Now you need to show that $\kappa(t)$ has two distinct critical points $t_1$ and $t_2$, at which $\kappa'(t_i)=0$.

Comment: Hmm okay. By the way, $\dot{\gamma (t)}$ and $\gamma '(t)$ are the same. Right? Please I solve this by your help. And I Will write here. Can you check? I dont want to do mistake. And dont want to learn false. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Yes I wrote $\gamma'$ to mean the derivative of $\gamma$ with respect to $t$ which can also be written as $\dot{\gamma}$.

Comment: $$\gamma "(t)= (-cost+4sin(2t), -sint-4sin(2t))$$ Well, how can I do $$\gamma '(t) \times \gamma "(t)$$ ?

Comment: Imagine the vector being in three dimensions instead of two, and so just add a zero to the $z$ component of each vector.

Comment: That's, for example $(a,b)\times (c,d)= (ac+ad, bc+bd)$ is it?

Comment: No, $(a,b)\times(c,d)=(a,b,0)\times(c,d,0)=(0,0,ad-bc)$ and so $\|(a,b)\times(c,d)\|=|ad-bc|$.

Comment: Okay I dont know this equation. Thank you :)